# Sendmail Default IP

Tags: ip, sendmail

I'm wanting to set the default IP used by sendmail to send email. I've looked through sendmail.mc and through the options availible in webmin and just can't find the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
CLIENT_OPTIONS('Addr=aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd')
```

That is likely a m4 config directive.

This is what you'd add to /etc/sendmail.cf I think:

```
O ClientPortOptions=Address=1.2.3.4
```